# How to close one program after another is closed

Tags: batch-file

```
@ECHO OFF
start /d C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\ ****.txt
start /d C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\ ****.xlsx
```

This is the code I have written to start program simultaneously, but in the same file, I want the one program to automatically close another. 
For example, when I click on this .bat file, both will open but as soon as I close one program like ****.xlsx it should close the .txt file as well without my interference. Is there any way this is possible in the same .bat file?

Thanks.

Comment: Run a loop to check for Excel. If Excel stops executing kill Notepad. Beware that you might loose data that way. In addition it's not easy/maybe impossible to check whenever you have a specific XLSX open.

Comment: @Seth You can look for the lock file ...

Comment: Right, it's stored in the directory of the original as a hidden file, correct?

Comment: I am a newbie. Can you help with the code. And as far as the files are concerned, I am using OBS(Open Broadcaster Software) with a game to record it. So when i execute the .bat file, I want to run the OBS and game and when I close the game, I want OBS to be closed as well.

Comment: This is the actual code                                                                    
@ECHO OFF
start /d "D:\OBS Studio\obs-studio\bin\64bit" obs64.exe
start /d C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\ <game-name.url>                                                                                <game-name.url> cuz it isa steam game.